# Is there an Italian expression for "I've forgotten more than you'll ever know?"

Tags: idioms

Is there an Italian idiomatic expression for "I've forgotten more than you'll ever know"?

Comment: If you ask for something similar in Italian you should probably explain what's the meaning of the English expression. In Inglese di solito la frase è usata da un anziano verso una persona giovane che non gli dà retta per indicare che lui ha più esperienza. Da che so di per sé non è inteso come un insulto ma alcuni lo prendono come tale e c'è chi usa la frase come per dare dell'ignorante.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Beh io l'ho interpretata come un modo per sminuire l'interlocutore affermando la propria superiorità nell'argomento (in modo un po' offensivo)... Del tipo  un professore dice a uno studente "I've forgotten more about math than you'll ever know".

Comment: @ Ant, si come detto c'è chi lo usa anche in quel modo, non è sempre così, ma una volta spiegato altri hanno indicazioni per suggerire un corrispondente

Comment: Is it an actual idiom? Or a quotation from some literary text, song or other? The oldest I could find is a [1953 song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Forgot_More_Than_You%27ll_Ever_Know). Does the phrase predate the song? (Questions for ELU, if anything, I know.)

Comment: @DaG I don't know, I have heard Marshall say it in a How I met your mother conversation, but there is also a Bob Dylan song from Self Portrait (1970) with that title (edit: it turned out it was a cover of the song you mentioned)

Comment: @DaG, apparently it is an actual idiom used as title of the song... some of the earliest places where I just found it are the 1811 "The Philadelphia Repertory" and the 1822 "The New Monthly Magazine and Literary Journal"

Comment: Great, @ErikvanDoren, thanks! My doubt is due to an idiom being, properly, «a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g. *over the moon*, *see the light*)», while this phrase has a perfectly intelligible literal meaning.

Comment: So - this would be an axiom, if you could prove it. * Kidding*  It would be a proverb - because although it is not an ancient saying, it is certainly a popular one. I  hear it very often, and it is quite rude and dismissive, although, like everything else, I could jokingly say it to a friend as a mild put-down.

Comment: @DaG, yes i know what you mean, im not sure to which degree literal meaning has to detach from the figurative. We could say that if you take it figuratively is "listen to me i have more experience" while literally comes the insult "you know nothing"? If I look at Wikipedia (a so-so source) "waste not, want not" its an idiom and seems even clearer than the sentence we are discussing. I never really thought too much about it until now that you brought it up... or i should say i never gave a fig?

Comment: @Msfolly, i must say not everyone means an insult or rudeness when they say it, it would be interesting to see if its a generational thing... Btw "being on thin ice" is also very clear in its meaning

Comment: @ErikvanDoren ??? Am I on thin ice?  ;-/

Comment: @Msfolly, nope, its another supposed idiom that to me seems very clear... after DaG comment I'm looking at all of them with suspicion :)

Comment: @Msfolly, rudeness-wise would you take "forgotten more than you ever knew" differently from "forgotten more than you'll ever know"? I could see how there could be a difference in the two and I don't know if one became the other or they are two separate things, I never heard anybody making a distinction in between the two.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Thanks for your remarks. In my – not so humble but well open-to-debate – opinion, both “waste not, want not” and “being on thin ice” are more idiom-y, independently of their clarity: the first by its fossilised, not completely grammatical form, and the second by its metaphorical use (in general we are not talking about someone actually on a frozen lake). Our phrase, on the other hand, might be literally true, at least in some cases (say, an erudite, forgetful guy talking to a young, ignorant one).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An idiom I've heard occasionally is "Ne devi mangiare, di pastasciutta...", implying that the listener hasn't eaten enough pasta (which is the same as to say that they are young) to be as knowledgeable as the speaker.

Comment: this is actually good! Thanks I think I'll go with that

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "Sapessi quante ne ho passate" or a more idiomatic "Ne ho passate di cotte e di crude"  - lit. - "I went through cooked and raw ones (all range of situations)". Hope this helps. Ciao.

Answer (score 3):

No, or at least not exactly.

You can have literal translations that suit the meaning such as "*Ho scordato più di quanto tu potrai mai imparare*", but no strictly idiomatic way.

Comment: @Ant It is to be noted that the sentence itself is not an idiomatic construct of English (to me it sounds quite literal?), so I'm unsure why you'd expect one in Italian. Maybe if you explain the reason behind the question we can help you find a better answer.

Comment: You are right, it is literal, but I think in english it's part of some body of "commonly known" phrases, it does not seems weird (see the comments above for origin of the phrase) On the other hand if I say that in italian it will feel weird to a certain degree. In any case it seems the best I can hope for.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't really fit, however if you say: "ne ho ingoiati di rospi", it would be about the same kind of thing that you try to say. 
Maybe somebody will come with a better answer.

Comment: Could you please explain the exact meaning of this Italian idiom?

Comment: I'm not sure whether *ingoiare rospi* has the slightest connection with the idiom in the question.

Comment: Yes, please do!  I am sure my translation of it is a laugh, too,  but it certainly sounds very evocative.  It made me laugh.  I think...   "I have never yet swallowed toads?"

Comment: @Msfolly, wide of the mark, keep trying it will help your Italian learning ;) hopefully you will get to it before maxadamo replies...

Comment: @Msfolly, and what I meant is just that if he replies he'd spoil the fun for you.

Comment: @Msfolly "I swallowed lots of toads", meaning I have seen and endured bad stuff (can sometime be used also to indicate experience, and not only charachterize the past events in a negative way). But yeah maxadamo as egreg said I don't think this is a good translation for the English idiom I'm interested in :-)